# Variable of a function are shared between different instance of that same function,my variable a'rent local to it's instance?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, variables

I made a function to add `<a>` tag in chat text and it worked fine, but it seems the variables of the function are shared between different instances of the function called from different chat rooms. I thought function variable were local, can anyone explain why I'm encountering this problem? Well I found out the code was wrong and a `<p>` tag the ajax function was adding to the string was interfering with this function. i fixed it by adding a space before the conflicting `<p>` tag and now it works fine...updated the code with english variable names too :)

```
function ajoutertagdelien(dataChat)
{
if (dataChat)
    {
}
   else
{
  dataChat = " ";
}
    var chatsendvar = dataChat;
var linkLocation, chatStringLeftPiece, chatfinal = "", chatStringRightPiece, lienfin, LinkAlone, LinktagString, LinkPiece;
var linkTagA = new Array();
var variablelocation = new Array();
var variablechatsend = new Array();
    var increment=0;
var earlierLinkLength = 0;
linkLocation = chatsendvar.indexOf("www.");
while (linkLocation != -1) {
    increment++;// 
    if (linkLocation != -1)
    {
            chatStringLeftPiece = chatsendvar.substring(0,linkLocation); 
        LinkPiece = chatsendvar.slice(linkLocation,chatsendvar.length); 
        lienfin = LinkPiece.indexOf(" ");
        LinkAlone = LinkPiece.substring(0,lienfin);
        chatStringRightPiece = chatsendvar.substring(((lienfin + linkLocation)),chatsendvar.length) ;
        console.log( chatStringLeftPiece + " droit et gauche " + chatStringRightPiece  + " number of theloop in the while=" + increment);   
        LinktagString = "<a target='_blank' href='http://"+ LinkAlone+"'>"+LinkAlone+"</a>";    
        chatsendvar = chatStringLeftPiece + " " + chatStringRightPiece;
        linkTagA.push(LinktagString);
        variablelocation.push(chatStringLeftPiece.length + earlierLinkLength);
        earlierLinkLength = earlierLinkLength + LinktagString.length +1;
            }
        linkLocation = chatsendvar.indexOf("www.");
    } 
    for (var x = 0,  j = linkTagA.length; x<j; x++) {
             chatsendvar = chatsendvar.split('');
             chatsendvar.splice((variablelocation[x]),1," "+linkTagA[x]+" ");
         chatsendvar = chatsendvar.join('');
        };
    return  chatsendvar;
```

}

Comment: nope, I called the function with diffenrent text from different chatrooms but the chatrooms's text get all mixed up together

Comment: If I do like you say the variables will be local to each instance of the function ?

Comment: And which variables exactly appear to be shared? Why do you think they do? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: The variables : locationdulien, chatmorceaugauche, chatfinal = "", chatmorceaudroit, lienfin, lienseul, balisedelien, lienmorceau; appear to be shared between different time that I called the function  simultaneously sending those text as parameter to that function but the truckload of differents variables that should not be shared are shared, the text in private chat and public are all mixed up together with extras bugs from misplaced <a> link tags ...

Comment: When there is only one chat room with text in it, it works fine, the text beginning with www. appear as click-able link on the page

Comment: "*that function is called by various ajax functions*" - could they mix it up maybe? Does one of that ajax functions have the classic closure-in-a-loop problem?

Comment: I don't see any reason why those variables would be "shared". Could it rather be a problem with the data you are passing to the function? I'm afraid without being able to run the code and reproduce the the problem, it's going to be *very* difficult to help you, especially since the variable and function names are not in English.

Comment: I have fixed the issue, it came from a <p> tage of the date added in the by the ajax, it was considered part of the link my my function so it was messing up all the stuff, well the variable aren't shared they are local to each instance of the function ...anyways i fixed it by adding a space in front of the <p> tag of the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this code to detect links in a text?
I know that's not what you asked, but this small function can do this. It can detect links beginning with `www.` or `http://` and even handles url parameters, like `?a=1&b=2`. Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJe98/1/).
The regex could be modified to handle `https://` or url encoding for example, but you get my point.

```
function makeLinks(text) {
    return text.replace(/(?:http:\/\/|(www\.))([\w\d.\/\?&=]+)/gi, '<a target="_blank" href="http://$1$2">$1$2</a>');
}
```

Comment: I know but I'm too lazy to learn the regex... I'm supposed to have learned it but I've never understood it quite...Are the performances will be much better If I implement that ?

Comment: It's really not that difficult, just seems complicated. There are great online regex testers, like [regex101](http://regex101.com), where you can build your expression. And yes, the performance will be much better. Also you'll have significally less code, so despite the cryptic regex, the code itself will be more readable.